# what is the difference between `pyenv global x.y.z` and `pyenv shell x.y.z`?

Tags: python, pyenv

I installed:

```
$ pyenv install 3.7.3
$ pyenv versions
system *
3.7.3
$
```

Then to switch from system (Python 3.8.5) to 3.7.3 I can use both **global** and **shell**:

```
$ pyenv global 3.7.3
$ python3 --version
3.7.3
$ 
$ pyenv global system
$ python3 --version
3.8.5
$ 


$ pyenv shell 3.7.3
$ python3 --version
3.7.3
$ 
$ pyenv shell system
$ python3 --version
3.8.5
$
```

What is the difference between the switch using **global** and the one using **pyenv shell** ?

Note: If we mix `pyenv shell`  and `pyenv global` we get strange results

on my `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
  eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
fi
```

Comment: The `pyenv` commands are actually quite well explained in the documentation: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pyenv global` reads/writes the `~/.python-version` file. In the absence of any other clues, pyenv uses this file to determine which python version to use.

`pyenv shell` sets the `PYENV_VERSION` environment variable for that shell. AKA it's equivalent to export PYENV_VERSION=3.9.1 for example. That means that this is temporary - when the shell exits, this command is lost until next time.

You can see from [the docs](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#choosing-the-python-version) how the python version is chosen:

> The PYENV_VERSION environment variable (if specified). You can use the
> pyenv shell command to set this environment variable in your current
> shell session.
>
> The application-specific .python-version file in the current directory
> (if present). You can modify the current directory's .python-version
> file with the pyenv local command.
>
> The first .python-version file found (if any) by searching each parent
> directory, until reaching the root of your filesystem.
>
> The global $(pyenv root)/version file. You can modify this file using
> the pyenv global command. If the global version file is not present,
> pyenv assumes you want to use the "system" Python. (In other words,
> whatever version would run if pyenv weren't in your PATH.)